# php error it says undefined vehicle and undefined submit

Tags: php

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","furniture");
$vehicle= $_POST['vehicle'];
if($_POST["Submit"] == "Submit")
{
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($vehicle);$i++)
    {
        $query="INSERT INTO events (status) VALUES ('".$vehicle[$i]."')";  mysqli_query($query) or die (mysqli_error());
    }
    echo "updated";
}
?>
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="test.php" method="post">
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> I have a car<br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

I'm getting this error:

> Undefined index: Submit in C
>   Undefined index: vehicle in C

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. Never insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: Have you checked what `$_POST` actually contains?

Comment: Check your $_POST variable like `print_r $_POST;`. Then you will find your error quite fast.

Comment: It means there is no variable with that value

Comment: submit works only when you click submit button. When the form is loaded, the button is not clicked, so it will show the error

Comment: use if(isset($_POST['submit']))

Answer (score 0):

You missed a parameter in `mysqli_query`. Put this : `mysqli_query($conn,$query)`

and also check whether your `$_POST` contains an array or not by `var_dump`

Answer (score 0):

Change ur code like this

```
if(isset($_POST["Submit"]))
{
    $vehicle= $_POST['vehicle'];
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($vehicle);$i++)
    {
        $query="INSERT INTO events (status) VALUES ('".$vehicle[$i]."')";  mysqli_query($query) or die (mysqli_error());
    }
    echo "updated";
}
```